# Selenium executar tarefa até o fim

Tags: primefaces, spring, jsf-2.2, selenium-webdriver, junit

Nos testes com o Selenium, executando pelo Eclipse, quando executo vários ao mesmo tempo. Acontece os  erros:

- Primeiro, não termina de executar a tarefa abre outro browser.
- Começa a executar o segundo teste sem mesmo ter terminado o primeiro
- Problema como é com o mesmo usuário, e um usuário só pode ter uma sessão então
- Quando volta a terminar o primeiro teste, o sistema já invalidou a sessão.
- Reprovando o teste que nem mesmo executou porque perdeu a sessão.

Tentei muitas configurações já para que seja executado da seguinte forma.
Somente uma **thread e até o fim**, mas não obtive sucesso.

Dois motivos para esses testes serem assim, são testes de integração validam cenários muitos complexos simulam um usuário fazendo as operações sequencias dentro do sistema.

Como chego nesse objetivo. 
1 - Thread por vez executando a tarefa até fim, depois vai para a próxima assim até chegar no ultimo teste

Comment: Salve! Já conseguiu resolver? Pode postar a sua configuração? Está utilizando o plugin do Maven (failsafe)?

Comment: Postei como resolvi, mas queria que fosse só com annotation, mas nessas versões o selenium tem muitos problemas não resolvidos quanto a isso

Comment: E ai comenta na resposta de certo, foi útil. quando der certo posta ai como fez.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz varias configurações com annotations, chegam até funcionar algumas vezes mas apresentam uma instabilidade muito grande.

Então consegui entender que só com annotations não funciona, problemas do Selenium na hora de gerar o xml para executar os testes e configura o pool de thread para executar os testes.

Então resolvido assim:
**Tem a configuração do plugin e do arquivo do ngtest**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <propertie>
                <name>junit</name>
                <name>false</name>
            </propertie>
        </properties>
        <threadCount>1</threadCount>
        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

//arquivo de confugaração src/test/resources/testng.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none" preserve-order="true" thread-count="1"  >
    <test name="Test" parallel="none" preserve-order="true" thread-count="1" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.SuaClasse_de_teste_PrimeiraTest" />
            <class name="com.SuaClasse_de_teste_SegundaTest" />
            <class name="com.SuaClasse_de_teste_E_assim_por_conforme_sua_necessidade_de teste_Test" />
            <class name="com.SuaClasse_de_teste_Test" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
//veja o nome das classes ajuda a enteder o contexto
```

Comment: Marcelo, eu não utilizo o NG então não vou me atrever a te dar um direcionamento incorreto. O que eu sugiro é você utilizar o Failsafe pra executar os seus testes. Ele é feito para ser executado no contexto de testes de integração, o que parece ser o seu caso. A primeira coisa a fazer é separar os testes de unidade e integração. Dá uma olhada nesse exemplo: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/testng.html . Dá um toque se tiver problemas.